# JMS issue connecting from WebSphere Liberty to Apache TomEE Plume

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I need to connect from code running in WebSphere Liberty to an MDB in Apache TomEE Plume. I am using activemq-rar-5.16.3.

Here is the Java code:

```java
public void notifyListeners(String caseId) { 
    logger.debug("+notifyListeners");
    int timeToLive = 15 * 1000; // 15 seconds
    try {
        logger.debug("Creating context");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        logger.debug("Got Initial context");
        ConnectionFactory jmsFactory = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("jndi/JMS_BASE_QCF");
        logger.debug("Got Factory");
        JMSContext context = jmsFactory.createContext(); 
        logger.debug("Creating text message");
        TextMessage msg = context.createTextMessage(caseId);
        logger.debug("Sending text message");
        context.createProducer().setTimeToLive(timeToLive).send(jmsSendQueue, msg);
        logger.debug("Text message sent");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error("Caught Exception sending ActiveMQ Message : " + e, e);
    }
    logger.debug("-notifyListeners");
}
```

No matter what I try, the code hangs at `jmsFactory.createContext()`. There's no exception. It just hangs.

I can see from the Apache TomEE logs that an ActiveMQ listener has been created on `tcp://127.0.0.1:61616` and verified this with a `netstat` command.

I can't move to the later version of the rar because it relies upon a Java 11 JRE.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can debug this? Wireshark shows nothing, and changing the Liberty definition to point the ActiveMQ Connection Factory to `61615` changes nothing - so I don't think the `createContext` method is getting as far as contacting the ActiveMQ broker. It's hardly relevant, but this method runs in an asynchronous CDI event handler in Liberty. There is nothing untoward in the Liberty logs, and no FFDC events.

Some more details:

- Liberty: product = WebSphere Application Server 21.0.0.1 (wlp-1.0.48.cl210120210113-1459)
- Apache TomEE: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/9.0.52 (8.0.8)

My `server.xml` (relevent bits):

```xml
<!-- language: xml -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jpaContainer-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
    <feature>microProfile-3.3</feature>
    <feature>monitor-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>



<!--============================================= -->
<!-- Liberty to TomEE JMS over ActiveMQ Config    -->
<!--============================================= -->
<resourceAdapter id="activemq" location="C:\apps\liberty\ActiveMQRAR\activemq-rar-5.16.3.rar">
    <properties.activemq ServerUrl="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"/>
</resourceAdapter>

<jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jndi/JMS_BASE_QCF"> 
    <properties.activemq serverUrl="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"/> 
</jmsQueueConnectionFactory> 

<jmsQueue jndiName="jndi/worklistQueue"> 
    <properties.activemq PhysicalName="jms/worklistQueue"/> 
</jmsQueue> 
<!--============================================= -->
<!-- Liberty to TomEE JMS over ActiveMQ Config end-->
<!--============================================= -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits - I looked at the edited source and learned a few things.

Comment: Where is the `context` coming from that you're using in the `notifyListeners` method? ActiveMQ "Classic" (i.e. 5.x) doesn't fully support JMS 2 so you can't use the `JMSContext` API with it. In any event, when the call hangs you should grab a few thread dumps to see where the code is stuck.

Comment: @JustinBertram I define a <jmsQueueConnectionFactory> in the Liberty server.xml, and I had originally been injecting this into the notifyListeners method. But the Liberty server I am using is setup for JMS 2.0, so I may be mixing apples and oranges here. I will setup a clean server, with JMS 1.1 and see if it works there before resorting to thread dumps.  Do you know if I can replace ActiveMQ "Classic" in TomEE with Artemis? And if so, will it still work with ctivemq-rar-5.16.3 ?

Comment: JMS 2 is backwards compatible with JMS 1.1 (which ActiveMQ "Classic" fully supports) so you can still integrate using the ActiveMQ "Classic" JCA RA. You just can't use any APIs which are specific to JMS 2 (e.g. `createContext`). In any case, you can replace ActiveMQ "Classic" with ActiveMQ Artemis in TomEE and you can still using the JCA RA from ActiveMQ "Classic", but you still won't be able to use API calls specific to JMS 2 because that's not supported by that JCA RA. You'd have to use the ActiveMQ Artemis JCA RA.

Comment: Did you happen to get any thread dumps to see where the code is stuck?

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for that information. So I have some choices. I haven't taken any thread dumps yet, I will try to get some later tonight. Bit of pressure on here at the moment - you know how it goes. Will update here as soon as I have more info.

Comment: @JustinBertram - I have it working now. I dropped back to JMS 1 style, as per your suggestion, using context, session, producer, and all is good. Make a short answer with the essence of your suggestion, and I will be more than happy to accept it. Maybe someday soon I'll get to deploy Artemis :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main concern here is the use of `createContext()` in your `notifyListeners` method. ActiveMQ "Classic" (i.e. 5.x) doesn't fully support JMS 2 so you can't use the `JMSContext` API with it. JMS 2 is backwards compatible with JMS 1.1 (which ActiveMQ "Classic" fully supports) so you can still integrate using the ActiveMQ "Classic" JCA RA. You just can't use any APIs which are specific to JMS 2 (e.g. `createContext()`).